# how to open the console log in Opera browser? ( javascript problem )

Tags: javascript

thank you for your view. I am having poblem with Opera browser like this.

I coded a very simple program (javascript) like this

```
console.log('fullName');
```

and want to display it to the console, but when I click Ctrl + Shift + I (I am using Opera), here I got, as you can see by this picture [picture about the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5y1w.png)

It does not display the log "fullName" as I hope.

By the way, I also code anothe code like this

```
setInterval(function() {console.log('fullName')}, 1000)
```

instead of console.log, but it still nothing, as you can see

[picture of (setInterval)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNyv8.png)

Could you please give me some advice to show the console ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If you click on 38 messages instead of the main.js file, (left side of console window) what do you see?

Comment: I don't have Opare but on the right top of the console there is "38 hidden". So there must be a filter for the console which (I guess) is setup that way that it only shows errors on default. I f you click on the setting wheel next to "38 hidden" I guess you can change this filter